# how to solve npm deprecation installation error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-red

I am new to node-red interface, and I am trying to set up a distributed flow using [DNR editor](https://github.com/namgk/dnr-editor) created by JS Foundation. While attempting to install via both npm and git clone I have encountered many errors that prevented installation. Could someone please help me take a look at the problem and see what I have done wrong? I have copied the shell log to a text file with some images attached. Thanks in advance for your time and attention!

I tried to reinstall one "deprecated" package (bcrypt@3.0.) but the npm deprecate message still persist.

```
C:\Users\WILL>npm install -g dnr-editor
npm WARN deprecated bcrypt@1.0.3: bcrypt < v2.0.0 is susceptible to bcrypt wrap-around bug. Upgrade to bcrypt >= v2.0.0 for improved support for newer bcrypt hashes
npm WARN deprecated mongodb@2.1.21: Please upgrade to 2.2.19 or higher
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated mailparser@0.6.2: Mailparser versions older than v2.3.0 are deprecated
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@1.11.0: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated mimelib@0.3.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@2.1.0: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@2.0.0: This project is unmaintained
C:\Users\WILL\AppData\Roaming\npm\dnr-editor -> C:\Users\WILL\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\dnr-editor\red.js
```

Comment: open an issue on github of DNR Editor, they need to update their dependencies

Comment: These are just warnings not errors, nothing there will stop the application running

Comment: Just to add, the DNR project is a community-fork of the official Node-RED project. DNR is *not* part of the JS Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall --save bcrypt

&&

npm install --save bcryptjs